# Why does __int64 take 12 bytes inside struct?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have VC++ 2012 and noticed that if have something like

```
struct mystruct{
     char a[100];
     __int64 b; };
```

then sizeof(mystruct) would yield 112.

Why is this?

Comment: Padding for alignment purposes.

Comment: I need to get rid of it, because I'm writing the struct into a binary file

Comment: That's a non-sequiter. How the `struct` is stored internally has no effect on how you serialize it for storage to a file.

Comment: If you want to directly write the structure to a file (which *isn't* necessary, as @DavidSchwartz pointed out, and opens the door to endianity troubles and other possible problems that need addressing) you can probably employ `pragma pack` or its VC++ equivalent.

Comment: So you have a binary file format that stores 8-byte integers *not* aligned on 8-byte boundaries? Where is this format specified?

Comment: Reverse the member order. But along with others I strongly discourage the blast-o-binary approach to writing this stuff to disk file.

Answer (score 1):

Padding has to be added. Consider:

```
mystruct *a = (mystrct *) malloc (16 * sizeof (mystruct));
```

If there was no padding, some of the 64-bit integers wouldn't be aligned.

If you need data in a particular binary format, you *must* write code to put that data in that binary format. Don't try to do it by accident or by magic. Write code that produces precisely the bytes you want in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Why is this? Short answer, memory alignment.

The long answer is here: http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/